# Kubernetes set env variable to value from configMap after encoding it

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, configmap

I have a Pod configuration file very similar to [this example in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#use-configmap-defined-environment-variables-in-pod-commands) where I set a few env variables from a configMap file.
Now I need to add another variable but I need to `base64` encode it. I can easily do it when I take data from `values` by applying the `b64enc` function, but I don't know how to do it when getting the value from a `configMap`

This is what I can do

```
env:
  - name: PLAIN_VALUE
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: myconfig
        key: PLAIN_VALUE
  - name: ENCODED_VALUE_FROM_VALUES
    value: {{ .Values.myConfig.plainValue | b64enc | quote }}
```

I would like to do something like the following

```
env:
  - name: ENCODED_VALUE
    valueFrom:
      configMapKeyRef:
        name: myconfig
        key: PLAIN_VALUE
        transformation: b64enc
```

How  can I `b64enc` the `valueFrom: configMapKeyRef: myconfig/PLAIN_VALUE`?
P.S. `configMapRef` would also work, I can make a separate config file for that value.

Comment: Secret (instead of configMap) is option to use encoded variable https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario you should use secrets. It encodes the values in `base64`.

You can easily create a secret using [kubectl command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-secret-directly-with-kubectl), for example:

```
kubectl create secret generic test-secret --from-literal='your_value'
```

And it works similarly to configmap when it comes to [passing encoded values to pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data).

```
env:
  - name: ENCODED_VALUE
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: myconfig
        key: value
```